# Ubuntu 20.04 keeps hanging

Tags: 20.04, freeze

I recently switched to a new laptop installed Ubuntu 20.04 on one of the partitions (dual booted with Windows).

```
uname -a
Linux WORKCOM900 5.4.0-37-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 3 18:57:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

It uses an nVidia 2080 graphics card, and I am using the official nVidia driver but I have noticed the same freezing behavior without the nouveau driver.

Periodically while using the computer, Ubuntu just hangs for about 20 seconds.

There are a few variants of hanging.  On some occasions the mouse cursor can still move but I can't click on anything, usually it is like a flat-out freeze.

Can you help me know what is causing this, or what I should look at to figure out what is causing this?

**Update**

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Dell UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104M [GeForce RTX 2080 Mobile] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell TU104M [GeForce RTX 2080 Mobile]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 updated.

Comment: The driver is OK.